# New install Mint fails to find Bluetooth devices. Worked before

Tags: cinnamon, bluetooth, thinkpad

Unable to see any other Bluetooth devices on my Lenovo T410s running Cinnamon Mint 18.1 downloaded and installed yesterday. Worked before I wiped Cinnamon 17.1 to try MATE then when I returned to Cinnamon 18.1, it, too, fails to find devices.

Here's some data from the system.

> inxi -Fxz
>
> System:   Host: me-T410s   inxi -Fxz
>
> System:   Host: me-T410s
>   Kernel: 4.4.0-66-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 5.4.0)
>   Desktop: Cinnamon 3.2.7 (Gtk 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.2)
>   Distro: Linux Mint 18.1 Serena
>
> Machine:   System: LENOVO (portable)   product: 2904HCU   v: ThinkPad
>   T410s   Mobo: LENOVO model: 2904HCU   Bios: LENOVO   v: 6UET69WW (1.49
>   )   date: 04/25/2012   CPU: Dual core Intel Core i5 M 560 (-HT-MCP-)
>   cache: 3072 KB flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx)
>   bmips: 10639   clock speeds:   max: 2667 MHz   1: 1199 MHz   2: 1199
>   MHz   3: 1466 MHz   4: 1199 MHz      Graphics:   Card: Intel Core
>   Processor Integrated Graphics Controller bus-ID: 00:02.0   Display
>   Server: X.org 1.18.4   drivers: intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)   tty
>   size: 80x24     Advanced Data: N/A for root   Audio: Card Intel 5
>   Series/3400 Series High Definition   Audio driver: snd_hda_intel
>   bus-ID: 00:1b.0   Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture   v:
>   k4.4.0-66-generic      Network:    Card-1: Intel 82577LM Gigabit
>   Network Connection   driver: e1000e   v: 3.2.6-k   port: 1820
>   bus-ID: 00:19.0   IF: enp0s25   state: down mac:   Card-2: Intel
>   Centrino Advanced-N 6200   driver: iwlwifi   bus-ID: 03:00.0   IF:
>   wlp3s0   state: up   mac:
>
> Drives:   HDD Total Size: 160.0GB (8.8% used)   ID-1: /dev/sda
>   model: INTEL_SSDSA1M160   size: 160.0GB   temp: 0C
>
> Partition:   ID-1: / size: 143G   used: 9.5G (7%)   fs: ext4   dev:
>   /dev/sda1
>
> ID-2: swap-1 size: 4.08GB  used: 0.00GB (0%)   fs: swap   dev:
>   /dev/sda5   RAID: No RAID   devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel
>   module present
>
> Sensors:  System Temperatures:   cpu: 46.0C   mobo: 0.0C
>   Fan Speeds (in rpm):   cpu: 4020
>
> Info:   Processes: 214   Uptime: 36 min   Memory: 1056.1/3749.5MB
>   Init: systemd runlevel: 5   Gcc sys: 5.4.0   Client: Shell (bash 4.3.461)
>
> bluetooth on
>   bluetooth = on
>
> bluetoothctl [NEW]
>   Controller 5C:AC:4C:C0:83:57 me-T410s [default]